# Is it safe to memset() an std::iterator variable before assigning?

Tags: c++, std

Is this bit of code safe?

```
int main() {

    struct {
        int foo;
        int bar;
        std::list<...>::iterator it;
    } foobar;

    memset(&foobar, 0, sizeof(foobar));

    foobar.it = ...;
}
```

I'm thinking it's safe because `std::iterator` doesn't seem to override `operator=`.  Is this a valid reasoning?

Comment: Completely invalid reasoning and extremely bad code. You **never** use `memset` on non-PODs.

Comment: Comment should be an answer, no?

Comment: For C++, it's best to just forget that `memset` even exists. Even on the (rare) occasion that it might be safe, there's no good reason to use it anyway.

Comment: Ok, the reasoning was that even if I hose the instance, it'll be *reinitialized* by the assign anyway..  But I've now realized that the instance could have inter-dependent pointers with static entities.

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't matter what `std::iterator` does, because `std::list<...>::iterator` might do something different. It isn't even required to inherit from `std::iterator`, but if it was then it still would overload operators that `std::iterator` doesn't. The increment operators, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Assignment operator generally assumes that its left-hand side (recipient) operand has a valid state before assignment.

Meanwhile, you are steamrolling these zeros over possibly non-trivially constructed object of `std::list<...>::iterator` type. This can only work what you have intimate knowledge about the exact properties of `std::list<...>::iterator` and you know that filling it with zeros produces a valid object.

Comment: Even if setting it to zero produces a "valid object" `memset` is **still** bad. Consider a smart-pointer type of object, which contains only one data member: a pointer. A `memset` may cause a memory leak. Consider a lock type object. A `memset` may cause the locked object to forget to unlock itself. The bottom line is **DON'T USE `memset` on any non-POD types**

Comment: @Nik B.: Er... What is it you are trying to say? You began with unconditional "No", and then you yourself make your statements conditional with regard to POD or non-POD types. So, what is that "No" is supposed to mean then? And what makes you think that this not the same thing I was talking about?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your first paragraph, but your second pretty much answered my question.

Comment: @AndreyT: oops, yeah, that was a leftover. I cleared that up.

Comment: @antak He means that the operator= expects the object on which it operates to be in a "valid state" (a valid state being dependent on the object itself). By calling `memset` you are putting the object in a particular state. Is that state valid for that type of object. Maybe. Maybe not. If it's invalid and you call operator=, then the invariant that the object must be in a valid state no longer holds. And what happens then?

Comment: Ok, got it, you mean the implicit assignment operator that classes get if they don't override `operator=`.

Comment: It applies to both implicit and explicit assignment operators.

Answer (score 6):

`memset()`ing any non-trivial type is a Bad Idea. It is utterly unnecessary as well: just initialize the value:

```
struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    std::list<...>::iterator it;
} foobar = {};
```

It has the distinct advantage of being faster and also doing the Right Thing!

Comment: Cool.  Didn't know it could be initialized with a simple `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* memset types which have a constructor. You have no idea about the internal structure of an iterator, so you shouldn't go pounding it with a hammer.